# Why doesn't argument-dependent lookup work for std::make_tuple?

Tags: c++, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup

Writing `tie` instead of `std::tie` works here, because of argument-dependent lookup:

```
std::tuple<int, std::string> tup = std::make_tuple<int, std::string>(1, "a");
int i;
std::string str;
tie(i, str) = tup;
```

But why does `make_tuple` require `std::`?

Comment: For ADL to work you need one of the arguments to be in the namespace. This would work: `std::tuple<int, std::string> tup = make_tuple<int, std::string>(1, std::string{ "a" });`.

Comment: Because neither `1` nor `"a"` is under the `std` namespace, try `make_tuple(1, std::string("a"))`.

Comment: They are not the same; `"a"` is a `const char[2]`, while `str` is a `std::string`.

Comment: @wohlstad: C++20 would be required to do ADL **with** `<..>` (unless OP also defines some `make_tuple<..>` in global namespace).

Comment: @Jarod42 good point. I will add that to my answer.

Comment: The main point of `std::make_tuple()` is to avoid explicit specification of template parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for [ADL (Argument-dependent lookup)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) to work, you need one of the arguments to the in the `std` namespace.

This is the case in your call to `tie` (`str` is a `std::string`), but not in the call to `make_tuple` (neigher `1` nor `"a"` are).

You could use ADL by supplying a `std::string` like this:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvv--------
std::tuple<int, std::string> tup = make_tuple<int, std::string>(1, std::string{ "a" });
```

**Note:**
The code above, which attempts to be closest to your version, requires c++20 (where explicit template arguments don't prevent ADL).
However - this version which is also shorter works in earlier c++ versions:

```
std::tuple<int, std::string> tup = make_tuple(1, std::string{ "a" });
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the function's type parameters are not used in ADL?

Comment: That's just the way it is specified (you can see in the link I posted). I don't know the reasons behind it. This is a nice [article](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/04/26/what-is-adl/) - you can have a look in case I missed something about the rational. It looks like originally ADL was meant to solve a specific more narrow problem.